# mongodb c++ driver authenticate

Tags: c++, mongodb, authentication

I use ScopedDbConnection, it made in each db operation. If I do:

```
mongo::ScopedDbConnection conn(host);
conn->auth(BSON("user"<<"user1"<<"pwd"<<"password1"));
...
conn.done();
```

That means there will involve auth process in every db operation, this is unnecessary. In java driver, there is DB class which has a authenticate function, after "db.authenticate(...)", all subsequent operation can be execute rather than auth on each db connection like above code.

Is there way to just auth once in C++ driver?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution:

```
conn_ = new DBClientReplicaSet(...);
conn_->connect();
conn_->auth(BSON("user" << "xxx" << "password" << "xxx"));
```

Then you can use **conn_** to do any database operation.

Comment: This "conn_" can not be concurrent

Comment: yeah, maybe. In our application, we do not use **conn_** concurrently.